# Как вытащить из переменной string кусок текста находящийся между символами '\n'?

Tags: c++, строки

Как вытащить из переменной string f, кусок текста находящийся между k-ми символами '\n'? 
То есть например string f = "111232\naaaaaaa\n245642aaaa2\n21582". И мне нужен кусок текста между 2 и 3 символами '\n', то есть "245642aaaa2". И нужно записать ее в другую переменную типа string.

Comment: Это легко, но нужно ли? Какую реальную задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @VladD у меня в этой стринговской переменной f записаны пути к файлам через символ '\n' мне нужно написать функцию, которая будет выводить этот путь зная номер строки.

Comment: а почему не завести массив строк?

Comment: @user200355: Окей, а как они там оказались? Возможно, есть смысл сразу читать их как `vector<string>`?

Comment: @VladD  Получаю я эту переменную в функции, где считываю данные с сервера с помощью MySQL.Могу скинуть кусок кода.

Comment: string Connect(char host[], char user[], char password[], char database[], int port, int unix_socket, int clientflag)
{
 //"localhost", "root", "12345", "farabi4", NULL, NULL, 0
 MYSQL *conn;
 MYSQL_RES *res;
 MYSQL_ROW row;
 int i = 0;
if (res = mysql_store_result(conn)){
  while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) {
   for (i = 0; i <mysql_num_fields(res); i++){
    l = l + row[i] + '\n';
   }
  }
 }
 else
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
 mysql_close(conn);
 return l;
}

Comment: @user200355: Ну так отлично, зачем вы склеиваете результаты в строку, а потом хотите разобрать эту строку назад на куски? Складывайте результаты в `vector<string>` и возвращайте из `Connect` его.

Comment: @VladD я просто никогда не пользовался вектором, а каким образом я буду возвращать вектор из функции Connect и к нему обращаться так же, как к обычному массиву?

Comment: @user200355: именно так. сейчас напишу в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось в обсуждении, проблема на самом деле глубже: в функции, которая эту самую строку собирает. Перепишем эту функцию так:

```
vector<string> Connect(
    char host[], char user[], char password[],
    char database[], int port, int unix_socket,
    int clientflag)
{
    //"localhost", "root", "12345", "farabi4", NULL, NULL, 0
    vector<string> results;
    MYSQL *conn; // <-- нужно инициализировать, в вашем коде этого нет
    MYSQL_RES *res = mysql_store_result(conn);
    if (res)
    {
        MYSQL_ROW row;
        while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
        {
            for (i = 0; i < mysql_num_fields(res); i++)
                results.push_back(row[i]);
        }
     }
     else
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
     mysql_close(conn);
     return results;
}
```

(Кстати, откуда была строка `l` раньше? И откуда берётся `conn`?)

Затем вам нужно сохранить вместо `string` целый `vector<string>`, и обращаться к нужным элементам по индексу.

Comment: conn = mysql_init(NULL);mysql_query(conn, "SELECT path FROM src2"); //Делаем запрос к таблице string l = "";

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось:)

Comment: @user200355: Вот и отлично! Пожалуйста!